# Datapower service migration to WSO2

Tags: migration, ibm-datapower, wso2-esb

We have got the requirement of migrating Production environment of Datapower to WSO2. I never worked on Migration. Can anyone please let me know what would be the procedure of migrating the complete Datapower environment and also I want to know whether we can migrate only OAuth security feature of datapower to WSO2 ESB ?

Thankyou in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is; **No, you can't**!

There are literally no common ground between DataPower and WSO2 ESB nor are there any objects that would be similar or usable between the two.
WSO2 ESB is a chunky Java server implementation while DataPower is a firmware based Appliance using configuration only.

Not sure what you mean with the `OAuth security feature` but, again, that is a purpose built hardware based solution in DataPower, hardened and secure, and it has no equivalent in WSO2 ESB so you will need to build your own solution for OAuth, either as a separate Java servlet/app or build it as a WSO2 plugin.

You will need to document all the services in DataPower and then build them one by one manually in WSO2 ESB.
You will also (most likely) find that many of DataPower's functions can't easily be built in WSO2 ESB...